# No Returns Method in Moq

Tags: c#, .net-core, moq

I created a unit test class library using .NET Standard and this is how I implemented it. The version of Moq that I am using is **4.10.0**.

```
[TestFixture]
public class EmployeeBusinessTests
{
    private Employee _employee;
    private Mock<IEmployeeRepository> _employeeRepository;
    private Mock<IUnitOfWork> _unitOfWork;

    private EmployeeBusiness _employeeBusiness;

    [SetUp]
    public void SetUp()
    {
        _employee = new Employee
        {
            Id = 1,
            FirstName = "John",
            LastName = "Smith",
            BirthDate = new DateTime(1965, 12, 31)
        };

        _employeeRepository = new Mock<IEmployeeRepository>();
        _unitOfWork = new Mock<IUnitOfWork>();
    }

    [Test]
    public void AddEmployee_EmployeeIsNull_ReturnNull()
    {
        _employeeRepository.Setup(er => er.Add(new Employee()))
            .Returns(_employee); // No Returns method!

        // … Other code here
    }
}
```

Can you please help me understand why I can't find the **Returns()** method?

Comment: How does IEmployeeRepositoty.Add look like? Does it have a return value?

Comment: You cannot find `.Returns` method because `_employeeRepository.Add` has `void` return type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As has been covered in the comments, your `Add` method is `void` and therefore you cannot use `Returns` on your `Setup`.

For what you are trying to achieve, look at using `Callback` instead of `Returns`.

```
_employeeRepository.Setup(er => er.Add(It.IsAny<Employee>)).Callback<Employee>(e => _employee = e);

// Add code here to perform actions

Assert.IsNull(_employee);
```

This is a simplistic example based on your posted code and not how I would actually implement a repository (for example you can only ever have one `Employee` here).